# htaccess - All subdomains to one directory with hidden parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a simple content management system. My goal is to have user's websites at user.example.com, and their subpages at user.example.com/subpage without writing files for each user. In the end, I hope to obtain the subdomain and the directory as POST parameters (or read the URL and parse it), and grab data from a database based on that.

I am using a LAMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04. mod_rewrite is enabled and the following .htaccess produces a `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ [L,NC,P]
```

Comment: Might be easier to just use php and `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get it and route based on that instead of trying to use more complicated mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that `.htaccess` file? You seem to be trying to do all and nothing. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED is a DNS error, so the only way those directives could trigger that error is if `http://example.com/` does not resolve.

Comment: I was thinking of using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` as well, but I'm still having trouble rerouting all subdomains to a directory without changing the url.

Comment: @w3dk I am hoping to redirect all subdomains. My `example.com` resolves correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing all the subdomains point to the same area of the file system as the main domain then you don't have to do anything particularly fancy in terms of routing the URL. You don't need to "redirect" back to the main domain, because you are already at the correct area on the filesystem.

Then you can implement a fairly standard front-controller pattern. In its most basic form:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Then, in `index.php` you can examine `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the subdomain (the user) and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the URL-path (and an query string).

Alternatively, you can explicitly pass the subdomain to the controller (but there isn't really a need to do this, unless you wanted to pre-validate it for some reason). For example, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?user=%1 [L]
```

Here, `%1` is a backreference to the subdomain matched in the preceding `RewriteCond` directive. The first two `RewriteCond` directive ensures that no static resources are routed.